# Slow download, but fast upload speeds. Any ideas?

Tags: download, upload, performance

I have been having problems with my macbook on my home network. Speakeasy speed test gives me results of .6 Mbps DL and 4.09 Mbps upload. I took my computer to the mac store and had 25 Mbps DL speed. I replaced my router yesterday and had comcast give me a new modem today. When I plug directly into the modem I get about 10 Mbps download speed, but when wireless have only .6Mbps. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are there any other devices on your home network?

Answer (score 1):

A speed/duplex issue could cause this.  The modem may allow you to set the port to a fixed speed and duplex and the router may as well.  While Auto/Auto usually works, that is not always the case.  More info on the router and modem may help get a more detailed answer.

If you can, set the modem to say 100 Mbps Full dulex and the router the same.  Note that some will only set speed and not duplex.  In any case, it may require a bit of experimentation.